# Accessing the selected state of a dropdown list for conditional views

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to show something conditionally on the selected value in a dropdown list. Here's an example, which is obviously not working:

HTML :

```
<select id="sel">
    <option value="1" selected>aa</option>
    <option value="2">bb</option>
    <option value="3">cc</option>
</select>

<div id="aa1">aa</div>
<div id="bb1">bb</div>
<div id="cc1">cc</div>
```

jQuery :

```
$("#aa1, #bb1, #cc1").hide();

$('#sel').change(function(){
   var r = $(this).val().is(":selected");

   switch(r) {
     case '1':
       $("#aa1").show();
       break;
     case '2':
       $("#bb1").show();
       break;
     case '3':
       $("#cc1").show();
       break;
     default:
       $("#aa1, #bb1, #cc1").hide();
       break;
   }   
});
```

Here is a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/lotusms/cgnsh2v6/14/) as well

In my real implementation, I tried this:

```
$("#sel").on("change", function(){
    var r = $(this).val();
    if(r == "1"){
        $("#aa1").show();
    }else{
        $("#aa1").hide();
    }
});
```

The problem is, it only works on a change event (as you can see in the code) and I need it to read the loaded selected state when it loads on the DOM. So if the HTML has option 1 selected, the id=aa1 should automatically show, if I change it to another option, it should hide even though that new chosen option will be "selected". So I can't make any div show on a selected item because it will show all the time since one will always be selected. It needs to be in a certain way (i.e. when the option of value(1) is selected, do this, If the value(2) is selected, then do something else, etc.

I would rather use a case statement since I have several options with several views.

Thanks in advance guys

Comment: `$('#sel').on('change', ...).trigger('change')` will execute the event handler on page load

Comment: A simple map could do away with the ifelse and switch statements

Comment: @Taplar That trigger did it! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you can use `trigger()` to make the event listener execute on page load.

You can also use a map to reduce your if else or switch logic to a simple statement.

```js
var $selectionDisplays = $('.selectionDisplay');

$('#sel').on('change', function(e) {
  var valueMap = {
    '1': 'aa1'
    , '2': 'bb1'
    , '3': 'cc1'
  };
  var idToShow = valueMap[e.target.value];

  $selectionDisplays.hide();
  
  if (idToShow) $selectionDisplays.filter('#'+ idToShow).show();
}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sel">
  <option value="1" selected>aa</option>
  <option value="2">bb</option>
  <option value="3">cc</option>
</select>

<div id="aa1" class="selectionDisplay">aa</div>
<div id="bb1" class="selectionDisplay">bb</div>
<div id="cc1" class="selectionDisplay">cc</div>
```

Comment: I like the map approach. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/uxnqogdm/1/)**.

You could fire the event directly after the creation like:

```
$("#sel").on("change", function() {
  ...
}).trigger('change');
//Or
}).change();
```